# How long did the rebel base on Dantooine exist?

Tags: star-wars, the-rebel-alliance

We know from *A New Hope* (ANH) that there was a rebel base on Dantooine, this being supported by numerous references including within the ANH and several stories within *From a certain point of view*.

To summarise:

**So when was the rebel base on Dantooine used by the Rebel Alliance and when was it abandoned?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as my research goes, I have limited down the time that the Base existed from 2 BBY to 0 BBY- this being backed up by date in which the [meeting above Dantooine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Cargo) occurred (2 BBY) and the fact that it appears that the rebels have left in a hurry due to the military surplus left behind (*From a certain point of view* - [The Trigger](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trigger), as told by Dr Aphra.)